# Firebase firestore giving null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from my firebase firestore and everything seems correct to me but I am getting blank on my text view.I am also not getting any error in the logs related to the profile activity and class.I have used firestore the same way in my other application and it worked perfectly fine there.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkrDA.png)
it would be amazing if you guys could help me as I am stalled because of this error.

**My logcat**

```
2020-05-29 14:53:38.381 4280-4280/? E/Zygote: v2
2020-05-29 14:53:38.385 4280-4280/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
2020-05-29 14:53:43.495 4280-4280/com.example.feedme E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

My java code:

```
 import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView namea;
    CircleImageView circleImageView;
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    String user_id;
    String url;
FirebaseFirestore fStore;
FirebaseAuth fAuth;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        Toast.makeText(this, user_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.profilepictureuser);
        Picasso.with(this).load(url).resize(400, 400).centerCrop().into(circleImageView);
namea = findViewById(R.id.profilename);
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user_id = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


        DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("User data").document(user_id);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                namea.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Full name"));
            }
        });

            bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation1);
            bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.profilelogo);



            bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.profilelogo:
                        return true;
                    case R.id.home:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), homepage.class));
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
            });


        }
    }
[enter image description here][1]
```

**The layout file for the profile**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".profile">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            android:id="@+id/profilepictureuser"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profilename"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp" />



    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation1"
        android:background="#047cfb"
        app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"
        app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My firestore collection:

[image]

**I added a toast to check the user_id here's the screeshot and the code is updated btw**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkrDA.png)

Comment: Update I made some changes to the rules and now I am not getting that error or any other error.Even after this I am not getting the data from firestore into the textview.The textview is just empty.

Comment: If the behavior changed, update your quesetion to include the updated code, the updated behavior, and possibly the security rules (if those are relevant).

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for replying.I have edited my question and all the files.I have also added a screenshot of my firebase firestore.Please view the question again and try to help me.Thanks guys.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for replying.I have edited my question and all the files.I have also added a screenshot of my firebase firestore.Please view the question again and try to help me.Thanks guys.

Comment: I also just figured out that whenever I am trying to pass data between activities I am getting blank in the other activity I think it's the same issue.

Comment: If you log `user_id` right before you use it to load a document, what does it output? Please include the updated code and its output in your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this is the updated code

Comment: @Frank I have tried to log or make a toast from the user_id and it does show the user id to me.

Comment: Good to hear. But please include the updated code that logs the value and its output in your question, so that we can see it too.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited and added an image url for the screenshot of the toast for the user_id please check.

Comment: That toast shows a different UID than you have in the screenshot of the database. Your code loads a document based on the UID of the current user, it won't be loading the document you've shown for the user/UID your toast shows.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it does actually.I made a mistake there by putting the wrong images but the code shows the same image as the one in firstore.Can you please look at the problem.Why I also cant pass data between activities?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please help me man.